# How do I change what is rendered in a javascript called from a view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am calling the twitter widget from a file twitter_widget.js using this code:

```
=javascript_include_tag "twitter_widget"
```

In a view of a controller written in haml.

Everything is functioning but all the URLs are rendering with the contents of the href in parenthesis as can be seen in this screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELDrh.png

I've googled around, and I'm new to rails, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing please clearly state the problem and what you require.

Comment: Show us the relevant code from your view and controller, and maybe post twitter_widget.js somewhere. We need to see your code to help.

Comment: Well, I feel sheepish. I forgot to disable the dev portions of blueprint.css I was using for an earlier layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was definitely bluprint.css. Once I disabled blueprint view rendered as expected.